# Program doesnt continue after long time foreach in worker role

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have `C# worker-role` which downloading files encoding them and uploading to FTP , due to field of files I have in `XAML` file which define workrole foreach loop.

After all files are downloaded,encoded and upload I have there code activity which sends me email.

My problem is that when I run this workrole and there are for example 10 files each 1,5 GB huge the foreach loop takes about 2 days to complete then the email activity doesnt hit and workrole ends in froeach loop but when i run it witth 10 files each 10 Mb huge the email activity is hitted and processed what could it be ?

```
<Foreach loop..../>
    <Sequence sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="586,146">
      <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
          <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
        </scg3:Dictionary>
      </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <local1:FeedbackEmail sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" IngestFTPConfig="IngestFTPConfig] />
</Sequence>
```

Comment: Could you post some code, please?

Comment: Well if you know how azure workrole XAML looks , then you must know that its just XAML file where is defined code activity sequence ... and it has grafic UI ... the problem is not in code... it just doesnt hit the sequence becouse foreach loop take so mutch time... its probably a bug .. its a generic problem, no code is needed but i edited the question with my code..